# Can't parse a 2nd page using beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to navigate a website using beautifulsoup. I open the first page and find the links I want to follow, but when I ask beautiful soup to open the next page, none of the HTML is parsed and it just returns this

```
<function scraper at 0x000001E3684D0E18>
```

I have tried opening the second page in its own script and it works just fine so the problem has to do with parsing a page from another page.

I have ~2000 links I need to go through so I created a function that goes through them. Here's my script so far

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import lxml

# The first webpage I'm parsing
my_url = 'https://mars.nasa.gov/msl/multimedia/raw/'

#calls the urlopen function from the request module of the urllib module
# AKA opens up the connection and grabs the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)

#imports the entire webpage from html format into python. 
# If webpage has lots of data this can take a long time and take up a lot of 
space or crash 
page_html = uClient.read()

#closes the client
uClient.close()


#parses the HTML using bs4
page_soup = soup(page_html, "lxml")

#finds the categories for the types of images on the site, category 1 is 
RHAZ
containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "image_list"})

RHAZ = containers[1]


# prints the links in RHAZ
links = []
for link in RHAZ.find_all('a'):
#removes unwanted characters from the link making it usable.
formatted_link = my_url+str(link).replace('\n','').split('>') 
[0].replace('%5F\"','_').replace('amp;','').replace('<a href=\"./','')
links.append(formatted_link)

print (links[1])
# I know i should be defining a function here.. so ill give it a go.
def scraper():
pic_page = uReq('links[1]') #calls the first link in the list
page_open = uClient.read() #reads the page in a python accessible format
uClient.close() #closes the page after it's been stored to memory
soup_open = soup(page_open, "lxml")
print (soup_open)
print (scraper)
```

Do I need to clear the previously loaded HTML in beautifulsoup so I can open the next page? If so, how would I do this? Thanks for any help

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you are trying to do exactly? It looks like you might be looking for the "Rear Hazard Avoidance Cameras" images/links in particular?

Comment: The first part of the script collects all the links for the rear haz. avoidance cam (RHAZ) and puts them into url format. I then want to open each link and download the pictures on those pages.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make requests from the urls scraped from first page...check this code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://mars.nasa.gov/msl/multimedia/raw'
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'lxml')
img_list = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'image_list'})
for i in img_list:
    image = i.find_all('a')
    for x in image:
        href = x['href'].replace('.', '')
        link = (str(url)+str(href))
        req2 = requests.get(link)
        soup2 = BeautifulSoup(req2.content, 'lxml')
        img_list2 = soup2.find_all('div', attrs={
            'class': 'RawImageUTC'})
        for l in img_list2:
            image2 = l.find_all('a')
            for y in image2:
                href2 = y['href']
                print(href2)
```

Output:

```
http://mars.jpl.nasa.gov/msl-raw-images/proj/msl/redops/ods/surface/sol/02172/opgs/edr/fcam/FLB_590315340EDR_F0722464FHAZ00337M_.JPG
http://mars.jpl.nasa.gov/msl-raw-images/proj/msl/redops/ods/surface/sol/02172/opgs/edr/fcam/FRB_590315340EDR_F0722464FHAZ00337M_.JPG
http://mars.jpl.nasa.gov/msl-raw-images/proj/msl/redops/ods/surface/sol/02172/opgs/edr/fcam/FLB_590315340EDR_T0722464FHAZ00337M_.JPG
http://mars.jpl.nasa.gov/msl-raw-images/proj/msl/redops/ods/surface/sol/02172/opgs/edr/fcam/FRB_590315340EDR_T0722464FHAZ00337M_.JPG
http://mars.jpl.nasa.gov/msl-raw-images/proj/msl/redops/ods/surface/sol/02171/opgs/edr/fcam/FLB_590214757EDR_F0722464FHAZ00341M_.JPG
http://mars.jpl.nasa.gov/msl-raw-images/proj/msl/redops/ods/surface/sol/02171/opgs/edr/fcam/FRB_590214757EDR_F0722464FHAZ00341M_.JPG
http://mars.jpl.nasa.gov/msl-raw-images/proj/msl/redops/ods/surface/sol/02171/opgs/edr/fcam/FLB_590214757EDR_T0722464FHAZ00341M_.JPG
http://mars.jpl.nasa.gov/msl-raw-images/proj/msl/redops/ods/surface/sol/02171/opgs/edr/fcam/FRB_590214757EDR_T0722464FHAZ00341M_.JPG
http://mars.jpl.nasa.gov/msl-raw-images/proj/msl/redops/ods/surface/sol/02170/opgs/edr/fcam/FLB_590149941EDR_F0722464FHAZ00337M_.JPG
http://mars.jpl.nasa.gov/msl-raw-images/proj/msl/redops/ods/surface/sol/02170/opgs/edr/fcam/FRB_590149941EDR_F0722464FHAZ00337M_.JPG
http://mars.jpl.nasa.gov/msl-raw-images/proj/msl/redops/ods/surface/sol/02170/opgs/edr/fcam/FLB_590134317EDR_S0722464FHAZ00214M_.JPG
http://mars.jpl.nasa.gov/msl-raw-images/proj/msl/redops/ods/surface/sol/02170/opgs/edr/fcam/FLB_590134106EDR_S0722464FHAZ00214M_.JPG
http://mars.jpl.nasa.gov/msl-raw-images/proj/msl/redops/ods/surface/sol/02170/opgs/edr/fcam/FLB_590134065EDR_S0722464FHAZ00214M_.JPG
http://mars.jpl.nasa.gov/msl-raw-images/proj/msl/redops/ods/surface/sol/02170/opgs/edr/fcam/FLB_590134052EDR_S0722464FHAZ00222M_.JPG
http://mars.jpl.nasa.gov/msl-raw-images/proj/msl/redops/ods/surface/sol/02170/opgs/edr/fcam/FLB_590133948EDR_S0722464FHAZ00222M_.JPG
```

Comment: What do you mean? it will print all the urls